# How could I share my python command line tool to the wild

Tags: python

I have just create Python command line tool([xiber](https://github.com/liaa/xiber)) called xiber.py that creating a iPad.xib file from a iPhone.xib. On my own computer I do:

```
alias xiber='python path_to/xiber.py'
```

Then I can use 'xiber' anywhere in my own computer. I want share this tool to other developer.
My question is: How could they use it without do the **alias xiber='....'** stuff and just using the **xiber** command.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your question about packaging and distributing (for specific OS' and distributions)? Python has a very detailed documentation on distributing python modules/programs (unfortunately a bit verbose): https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/index.html

Comment: @try-catch-finally I think it is. Take a npm example: '> npm install -g express'. when installing is done, I can use '> **express**' command anywhere on my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup your Git repo like this:

```
bin/
  xiber           # Formerly index.py
README.md
setup.py
```

In the `setup.py` file.

```
from distutils.core import setup

# Typing this from memory (not tested).
setup(
    name    = 'Xiber',
    version = '0.1',
    scripts = ['bin/xiber'],
    # Other options if desired ...
)
```

People who want to install your script can use ordinary tools like `pip` or `easy_install`, which will put your script in the appropriate `bin` directory of the Python installation. For example:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/liaa/xiber
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with hyperlinks to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

a way is to provide a xiber bash script and a xiber.bat batch file in a /bin/ folder that is distributed with the project.  Then the end user can make sure to add the bin folder to their PATH

Comment: Thanks @Josh Petitt, But this is a litter bit tedious for end-user. I think they don't need to do the moving files around thing.

Comment: @liaa, no moving by the end user.  I was basically saying the same thing as FMc, but FMc gave a better python answer since it uses setup.

Answer (score 0):

## Create executable by PyInstaller

Another option could be creating standalone executable file using [Pyinstaller](http://pythonhosted.org//PyInstaller/).

If you check the tutorial, you would find example starting with your scenario - turning Python script into executable (I used it and finally modified to the method "single file"), it works.